Slash Commands of Discord Bot can't be disabled
I wrote a discord bot, which executes to slash commands. One to basically role a die and one to show a random card image.
While testing I tried to limit the channels the commands can be used. Basically, because we want the commands to just be available in the voice channel rooms.
But nothing seems to work.
I created a fresh server and connected the bot.
The server has no roles configured. Just the one the bot created automatically.
In the intergration settings I disabled all channels:

but was still able to post the commands in every channel on the server.
I then tried to disallow all actions of the planechaser roll(the roll the bot created) in one category, but the bot was still able to post in those channels:

Commands look like this:


Are you testing with a user who has administrator privileges? Server administrators can use slash commands anywhere

well now I feel kind of stupid. You're right it is working. Other users can't execute the command. Will now try if this is also true on our real more complex server..
